# Computationally feasible way to fit data generated by sum of log normal and normal variables

Tags: r, normal-distribution, fitting, lognormal-distribution

I often run into data that has effects that go across a wide range of scales and are roughly log-normal, yet also have normal error terms added in, occasionally making some terms negative. Is there some way to fit a distribution to this data? If I can do this, I can check whether this model makes sense numerically and theoretically, which may make this data more interpretable.

More specifically, if $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are uncorrelated standard normal variables, then I believe samples $X$ are drawn from

$$X=e^{\mu_1+\sigma_1Z_1} + \mu_2 + \sigma_2Z_2$$

I am most specifically considering this in R, but I am open to other methods. I have considered writing out the likelihood function explicitly and optimizing with the four parameters and `nlm`, but the integration (convolution) was too complicated to run efficiently. I also considered using `nls` to fit the empirical cumulative distribution to the cumulative distribution, but I didn't find an easy way to specify that cumulative distribution.

Edit: two realistic cases I have encountered have been roughly:

1. N=10000, $\mu_1 = -3$, $\sigma_1 = 3$, $\mu_2 = 0$, $\sigma_2 = 10^{-3}$
2. N=1000, $\mu_1 = -9$, $\sigma_1 = 3$, $\mu_2 = 0$, $\sigma_2 = 10^{-6}$,

Comment: Maybe you could look for $\mu_1, \sigma_1, \mu_2, \sigma_2, (L_i), (N_i)$ which satisfy $L_i+N_i=X_i$ and maximize the likelihood $\prod P[L_i| \mu_1, \sigma_1]P[N_i|\mu_2, \sigma_2]$. Your first step would be guessing a decomposition of the $X$’s, then in even steps you’d optimize the parameters given the decomposition, while in odd steps you’d optimize the decomposition given the parameters, alternating until convergence.

Comment: Those are such enormous values of $\sigma_1$ and small values of $\sigma_2$ as to make the problem unsolvable with any reasonable precision.  If these values are realistic, you might just as well throw away the nonpositive values in the data and fit a Lognormal distribution.

Comment: It might not make a whole lot of difference but have you considered a model that is a "mixture" of a log normal and a normal rather than the sum of log normal and a normal?  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution)  That would depend on how you believe what the process is that generates the data.

Comment: @Jim Because the Normal term is intended to model measurement error, a mixture model is not indicated.

Comment: @whuber My usual approach is to add some small constant term such that the distribution is roughly log-normal (sometimes doing several runs with different parameters as a robustness check). I've done that for five or six versions of problems like this over the past few years. It felt like an inelegant hack, so I thought I'd explore fitting what I really think is going on.

Comment: @whuber I stand corrected.  I should have thought a bit more on that suggestion of a mixture distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using stochastic optimization to perform distribution matching. The idea is to generate a random a random vector, $Y$, using the parameter guesses at each iteration and then compare $Y$ to $X$ using a goodness-of-fit test statistic, which is returned to the stochastic optimizer.

The benefits to this approach are that it is fairly simple to code, and it converges to good estimates. The drawbacks are that it is somewhat computationally expensive, and each parameter must be within the upper and lower search bounds provided to the optimizer.

The R code below demonstrates the approach using the following:

1. The stochastic optimization function `StoSOO` from the `OOR` package
2. The Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test statistic
3. The two cases provided by the OP

Setup:

```
library(OOR)
set.seed(890018898)

# simulate case 1
n <- 1e4L
x <- exp(rnorm(n, -3, 3)) + rnorm(n, 0, 1e-3)

x <- sort(x)
pos <- which.max(x > 0)
```

First, get initial guesses for the parameters.

```
m1 <- mean(log(x[pos:n]))
s1 <- sd(log(x[pos:n]))
m2 <- 0
s2 <- sqrt(mean(x[1:(pos - 1)]^2))
```

To reduce the variability in the test statistic, sample $Y$ to have more elements than $X$. Also, have the function that returns the test statistic accept $\log(\sigma_1)$ and $\log(\sigma_2)$ to keep the guesses positive for the scale parameters.

```
os <- 100L # y oversampling for the KS statistic
nos <- n*os
w <- rep.int(c(-1, 1/os), c(n, nos))

f <- function(p) {
  # returns a value proportional to the KS statistic comparing x to a randomly
  # generated vector of size "nos" using the parameters in "p"
  y <- exp(rnorm(nos, p[1], exp(p[2]))) + rnorm(nos, p[3], exp(p[4]))
  max(abs(cumsum(w[order(c(x, y))])))
}
```

Run the stochastic optimizer.

```
system.time(
  res1 <- StoSOO(
    numeric(4), f, lower = c(m1 - abs(m1)/2, log(s1/2), -1, log(s2/2)),
    upper = c(m1 + abs(m1)/2, log(s1*2), 1, log(s2*2)), nb_iter = 1e3
  )
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  193.17    7.47  200.88
```

View the results.

```
res1$value
#> [1] 59.485
params1 <- setNames(res1$par, c("mu1", "sigma1", "mu2", "sigma2"))
params1[c(2, 4)] <- exp(params1[c(2, 4)])
params1
#>           mu1        sigma1           mu2        sigma2 
#> -3.0227077504  2.9517279929  0.0000000000  0.0009123462
```

`StoSOO` doesn't always converge tightly, so re-run it with tighter bounds in an attempt to find a better fit.

```
system.time(
  res2 <- StoSOO(
    numeric(4), f, lower = res1$par - abs(res1$par/4),
    upper = res1$par + abs(res1$par/4), nb_iter = 1e3
  )
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  198.06    9.16  207.51

res2$value
#> [1] 49.55
params2 <- setNames(res2$par, c("mu1", "sigma1", "mu2", "sigma2"))
params2[c(2, 4)] <- exp(params2[c(2, 4)])
params2
#>           mu1        sigma1           mu2        sigma2 
#> -3.0227077504  2.9914362045  0.0000000000  0.0009946919
```

Compare the values of the test statistic for the estimated parameters to those for the actual parameters. We find the estimated parameters fit $X$ better than the actual parameters because $X$ is a random sample.

```
mean(replicate(100, f(c(-3, log(3), 0, log(1e-3)))))
#> [1] 82.9047
mean(replicate(100, f(res2$par)))
#> [1] 51.9628
```

Repeat the exact same procedure for the second case.

```
# simulate case 2
n <- 1e3L
x <- exp(rnorm(n, -9, 3)) + rnorm(n, 0, 1e-6)

x <- sort(x)
pos <- which.max(x > 0)
# get initial guesses
m1 <- mean(log(x[pos:n]))
s1 <- sd(log(x[pos:n]))
m2 <- 0
s2 <- sqrt(mean(x[1:(pos - 1)]^2))

os <- 100L # oversampling for the KS statistic
nos <- n*os
w <- rep.int(c(-1, 1/os), c(n, nos))

system.time(
  res1 <- StoSOO(
    numeric(4), f, lower = c(m1 - abs(m1)/2, log(s1/2), -1, log(s2/2)),
    upper = c(m1 + abs(m1)/2, log(s1*2), 1, log(s2*2)), nb_iter = 1e3
  )
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   19.42    1.31   20.75

res1$value
#> [1] 14.33
params1 <- setNames(res1$par, c("mu1", "sigma1", "mu2", "sigma2"))
params1[c(2, 4)] <- exp(params1[c(2, 4)])
params1
#>           mu1        sigma1           mu2        sigma2 
#> -9.071491e+00  2.956245e+00  0.000000e+00  4.889863e-07

system.time(
  res2 <- StoSOO(
    numeric(4), f, lower = res1$par - abs(res1$par/4),
    upper = res1$par + abs(res1$par/4), nb_iter = 1e3
  )
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   19.40    1.17   20.61

res2$value
#> [1] 13.2725
params2 <- setNames(res2$par, c("mu1", "sigma1", "mu2", "sigma2"))
params2[c(2, 4)] <- exp(params2[c(2, 4)])
params2
#>           mu1        sigma1           mu2        sigma2 
#> -9.052825e+00  2.962846e+00  0.000000e+00  4.889863e-07

mean(replicate(100, f(c(-9, log(3), 0, log(1e-6)))))
#> [1] 21.1452
mean(replicate(100, f(res2$par)))
#> [1] 14.1672
```

Answer (score 1):

One feasible approach is *moment-matching*: finding parameters to match the first four moments of the data.

In this case $X=L+N$ with independent lognormal $L$ and normal $N$ normal, so (for example)
\begin{align}
E[X^2]&=E[L^2]\phantom{\mu_1+2\sigma_1^2)}+2\,E[L]\,E[N]\phantom{\mu_1\sigma_1^2/2)}+E[N^2]\\
&=\exp(2\mu_1+2\sigma_1^2)+2\mu_2\exp(\mu_1+\sigma_1^2/2) + (\mu_2^2+\sigma_2^2)
\end{align}
which uses standard formulas for the moments of the [lognormal](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lognormal%20distribution%20moments) and [normal](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=normal%20distribution%20moments) summands. This gives an equation in $\mu_1,\sigma_1,\mu_2,\sigma_2$, saying that the above expression should equal the average of the squares of the datapoints.

This and similar equations for $E[X], E[X^3], E[X^4]$ can then be solved numerically for $\mu_1, \sigma_1, \mu_2, \sigma_2$.

Comment: It would be nice to see a realistic example, because my intuition is that this is a very unstable numerical problem and that moment matching might not even succeed without very large amounts of data.

Comment: It would be nice to see some realistic parameters and sample sizes from the OP!

Comment: Agreed.  We do have a hint: the presence of some negative values implies $e^{\mu_1},$  $\mu_2,$ and $\sigma_2$ are of similar magnitudes.  But a lot hinges on how large $\sigma_1$ might be.

Comment: Or, if we can set $\mu_2=0$ for an unbiased error, we could use just three moments and get more stability.

Comment: I just added some parameters and sample sizes. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

To find the maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters we need the probability density function, $f(x)$, for $X=Z_1+Z_2$:

$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\exp \left(-\frac{(x- z_1-\mu_2)^2}{2 \sigma_2^2}-\frac{(\log (z_1)-\mu_1)^2}{2 \sigma_1^2}\right)}{2 \pi  \sigma_1 \sigma_2 z_1}dz_1$$

So with (likely) no nice closed-form for this integral we need to evaluate it numerically.  And as @whuber more than hints at in a comment a direct attack results in numerical instability because of underflow while evaluating the integrand.  We can avoid this and end up with a reasonable approximation of the density by determining the limits of integration not associated with underflow and even avoiding areas where the integrand is "close enough to zero."

Some R code below gives functions for the maximum likelihood estimates along with estimates of the associated standard errors.  Note that to get all parameters roughly the same order of magnitude I'm using $\log(\sigma_1)$ and $\log(\sigma_2)$ rather than $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, respectively, which also automatically enforces the restriction that the estimates of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ will be positive.

```
f <- function(z1, x, mu1, logsigma1, mu2, logsigma2)  {
  # Integrand for determining pdf of X = Z1 + Z2
  exp(-logsigma1 - logsigma2 - (x - z1 - mu2)**2/(2*exp(2*logsigma2)) -
    (-mu1 + log(z1))^2/(2*exp(2*logsigma1)))/(2*pi*z1)
}

logpdf <- function(x, mu1, logsigma1, mu2, logsigma2) {
  # Log of the pdf of X = Z1 + Z2
  lower <- max(10^-20, x - 4*exp(logsigma2))
  upper <- 4*exp(logsigma2) + max(0, x)
  result <- integrate(f, lower, upper, x=x, mu1=mu1, logsigma1=logsigma1, mu2=mu2, 
    logsigma2=logsigma2, subdivisions=100)[1]
  if (result$value == 0) {
     result$value <- -100
  } else {
     result$value <- log(result$value)
  }
  result$value
}

logL <- function(parms, d) {
  mu1 <- parms[1]
  logsigma1 <- parms[2]
  mu2 <- parms[3]
  logsigma2 <- parms[4]
  sum(unlist(lapply(d, logpdf, mu1=mu1, logsigma1=logsigma1, mu2=mu2, logsigma2=logsigma2)))

}
mle <- function(d, inits) {
  # Function that finds maximum likelihood estimates and standard errors
  mle.optim <- optim(inits, logL, d=d, control=list(fnscale=-1), hessian=TRUE)
  # Covariance matrix
  covmat <- -solve(mle.optim$hessian)
  list(mle=mle.optim, covmat=covmat, sd=diag(covmat)^0.5)
}
```

To use those functions consider the OP's two examples:

```
# Generate a random sample
  n <- 10000
  set.seed(12345)
  d <- exp(rnorm(n, -3, 3)) + rnorm(n, 0, 10^-3)

# Find maximum likelihood estimates
  system.time(results1 <- mle(d, c(-3, log(3), 0, log(10^(-3)))))
  #    user  system elapsed 
  #   88.16    1.74   90.14 
  # Estimates of mu1, sigma1, mu2, and sigma2
  with(results1$mle, c(par[1], exp(par[2]), par[3], exp(par[4])))
  # [1] -2.987227e+00  2.974923e+00 -4.195435e-05  1.006057e-03
  # Standard errors of mu1, logsigma1, mu2, and logsigma2
  results1$sd
  # [1] 0.0311040500 0.0089383883 0.0000552333 0.0445809578


# Generate a random sample
  n <- 1000
  d <- exp(rnorm(n, -9, 3)) + rnorm(n, 0, 10^-6)
 
# Find maximum likelihood estimates
  system.time(results2 <- mle(d, c(-9, log(3), 0, log(10^(-6)))))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   8.37    0.10    8.47 
# Estimates of mu1, sigma1, mu2, and sigma2
  with(results2$mle, c(par[1], exp(par[2]), par[3], exp(par[4])))
# [1] -8.967050e+00  1.099405e+00 -1.212325e-07 -1.380606e+01
# Standard errors of mu1, logsigma1, mu2, and logsigma2
# [1] 9.576075e-02 2.406230e-02 4.335842e-06 1.345771e-01
```

I have taken the liberty to use the true values of the parameters for starting values.  Your mileage may vary.

If either amount of computer time is larger than needed (as opposed to desired), then one can take advantage of the fact that the pdf of $X$ is relatively smooth.  One could use interpolation from a subset of values in the first 90% of the data and a regression with another subset of the upper 10% of the data (with the regression being of the form $a_0+a_1 \log(x) + a_2 (\log(x))^2$).  That would considerably reduce the number of calls to the numerical integration routine.